# C# app install in phone

Tags: c#, installation

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013.
i wonder if somehow can install application on phone(to use application on phone when user want's?
i know with ms visual studio can connect to windows phone, but how can install application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect device to the machine.when successfully connected, the device will be listed in visual studio.

From visual studio,select the device instead of simulator.

just deploy the solution

this will install your app into the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute Windows apps (I think this is what you want), throw the windows store.
Other methods are to develop ORM software or enterprise software.
Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn745654.aspx) for more detailed infos.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to deploy your own application to a test device.

1. First you have to make sure that you have installed the correct WindowsPhone SDK (depending on your phone OS).

https://dev.windows.com/de-de/develop/download-phone-sdk

2. Get a developer licence. If you are trying to deploy your application Visual Studio will give you a hint how to get one.
3. Create a project for windows phone or a universal app, something you can put on your device.

[image]

4. Connect your device and press "Start" in Visual Studio, the application gets compiled, deployed and started automatically.